# Diagonalization of a complex matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization

I'm trying to prove this:
Let $A$ be a complex matrix. If $A^2$ is diagonalizable and $A$ is invertible then $A$ is diagonalizable.

So, if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ then $\lambda²$ is an eigenvalue of $A^2$. I tried proving that $\dim (Ker (A-\lambda Id)) = \dim (Ker (A^2-\lambda^2 Id))$ but I couldn't get anywhere with that.

Thanks for helping me out.

Comment: Oops, misread what the premise was...

Comment: Note that in general $\dim(\ker(A - \lambda I)) \neq \dim(\ker(A^2 - \lambda^2 I))$, as with the matrix $$A=\pmatrix{1&0\\0&-1}$$ and $\lambda = 1$.

Comment: $A = S^{-1} B S$ for invertible $S$ and $B$ trigonal. Then $A^2 = S^{-1} B^2 S$. Maybe(!) $B^2$ not diagonal is a contradiction to $A^2$ diagonalizable. I am unable to proof that, but if I am right: $B^2$ is diagonal, then also $B$ is diagonal (as $A$ is invertible!).

Answer (score 3):

Hint: think about minimal polynomials. $A^2 - \lambda^2 I = (A - \lambda I)(A + \lambda I)$.

Comment: is the minimal polinomial of A² (x²-$\lambda_1²$)....(x²-$\lambda_n²$)?

Comment: Since $A^2$ is diagonalizable, its minimal polynomial is $p(t) = (t - \mu_1) \ldots (t - \mu_k)$ where $\mu_1, \ldots, \mu_k$ are the distinct eigenvalues of $A^2$.  Write each $\mu_j$ as $\lambda_j^2$.  So $A$ satisfies the polynomial ...

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $A^2$ is diagonalizable.  It follows that $A^2$ has a minimal polynomial of the form
$$
m_{A^2}(x) = (x - \lambda_1)(x-\lambda_2)\cdots (x - \lambda_k)
$$
Where $\lambda_i \neq 0$ for each $i$ and $\lambda_i\neq\lambda_j$ when $i \neq j$.  We note that $A^2$ must satisfy $m(A^2)=0$, and that $(A^2 - \lambda_iI) = (A-I\sqrt\lambda_i)(A+I\sqrt \lambda_i)$.  It follows that
$$
m_A^2(A^2) = (A-I\sqrt\lambda_1)(A+I\sqrt{\lambda_1})\cdots(A-I\sqrt\lambda_k)(A+I\sqrt{\lambda_k}) =0
$$
So, defining
$$
p(x) = (x-\sqrt\lambda_1)(x+\sqrt{\lambda_1})\cdots(x-\sqrt\lambda_k)(x+\sqrt\lambda_k)
$$
we note that $A$ satisfies $p(A) = 0$.  It follows that the minimal polynomial $m_{A}(x)$ of $A$ divides $p$.  It therefore follows that $m_A(x)$ has no repeated factors.  Thus, we conclude that $A$ is diagonalizable.

Comment: The premise is that A² is diagonalizable and I'm trying to prove that A is also diagonalizable...

Comment: whoops, I'll fix that then.

Comment: You should say your square roots aren't really square roots. It's quite misleading otherwise

Comment: @GabrielR. if they "aren't really square roots", then what are they?  Certainly, there is a canonical definition of the principal square root of a complex number.